# Why does one variable show different results?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm studying JS. Currently trying to understand Objects.

Can't understand why the same variable (item) can shows different result.

If I type `console.log(item);` it shows the keys of the object. If I use `console.log(menu[item]);` it shows the values.

```js
let menu = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};

for (let item in menu) {
  console.log(item); // item = width, height, title
}

for (let item in menu) {
  console.log(menu[item]); // item = 200, 300, My menu
}
```

I couldn't find the answer on my own. Probably because I even don't know how to describe my question correctly.

Comment: `item` is the key. When you log `item`, it logs the string. When you log `menu[item]`, it shows the value related to that key.

Comment: *"why the same variable (item) can shows different result"* - It isn't.  You're using the variable in two very different ways.  Are you familiar with the syntax of what `menu[item]` means and what it does?  Were you expecting a different result?  It's not really clear to me what exactly you're asking.

Comment: `menu` is an _object_.  Think of it like a hotel with many rooms, `item` is like the room number, and `menu[item]` is like the thing (or person) in the room with that number on the door. So if `item` is `width` then `menu[item]` is `menu['width']` which is `200`, but if `item` changes its value to `height` then `menu[item]` is `menu['height']` which is `300`  Do you get how `menu[item]` is like `menu['width']` if `item` is `width`?  Do you understand that `menu['width']` and `menu.width` are the same?

Comment: Objects created with _key: value_ pair, when you add for loop like `for (let item in menu)` you are simply saying "_I need to loop over the object keys where the object called **menu** and the keys will be **item**_", that's said,   `console.log(item)` will print the keys (_width, height, title_) and `console.log(menu[item])` will print the values (_200, 300, "my menu"_) because this syntax `menu[item]` will get the value of the provided key. (e.g. menu["width"] => 200)

Answer (score 0):

when inside a loop, menu[item] become something like this menu[width];
it's like you're saying "show me what is inside the menu in the key width: 200".